# Plot image in R with variable filename

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to save graphs in R using for-loop.

I can plot the graphs, but I am not am to save them with a variable filename.

Here is my script

```
for (i in unique(sample.ped$X.FamilyID))

{ 
print(i)
samplei<-subset(sample.ped, X.FamilyID == (i))
samplei

pedAlli <- pedigree(id = samplei$IndivididualID, dadid = samplei$PaternalID, momid = samplei$MaternalID, sex = samplei$Sex, famid = samplei$X.FamilyID, affected = samplei$Phenotype)

print(pedAlli)

svg(filename="(i).svg")
plot(pedAlli[(i)])
dev.off()

}
```

The expected output is creation of multiple svg files with variable filenames. Current output is one single svg file named (i).svg

Comment: Change `svg(filename="(i).svg")` to `svg(filename = paste0(i, ".svg"))`

Comment: That solved it. Thanks!